# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Anonymous Type#1>' to 'System.Array[]'

Tags: c#, linq

```
Array[] arr = {};

arr = Table<T>()
      .ToArray()
      .Where(g => g.EventDateTimeUTC.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == date)
      .GroupBy(l => l.Description.Distinct(), 
               (Description,items) => new{ key= Description, 
                                           count = items.Count()});

return arr;
```

I get this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Array[]'

Comment: Why must you use `Array[]`, it seems like a very odd choice of datatype. Would a IEnumerable not work for what you are trying to do?

Comment: I tried Ienemerable too but gives the same error message

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be diving head first in to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Below is the solution for your `X`, but I really suggest taking a step back and asking about `Y` in a different question.

`ToArray()` needs to be the last thing called to return an array.

```
Array[] arr = {};

arr = Table<T>()
      .Where(g => g.EventDateTimeUTC.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == date)
      .GroupBy(l => l.Description.Distinct(), 
               (Description,items) => new{ key= Description, 
                                           count = items.Count()})
      .ToArray();

return arr;
```

Comment: Notice that this will more than likely get him all the way to the scene of the next question. He's returning an anonymous type from a method.

Comment: Did not even see that anonymous type hidden in that group by. fair point.

Comment: +1 for actually answering question `X`

Comment: putting ToArray at the last which gives 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'System.Array[]'

Comment: Congratulations you are one step closer to solving `Y`, read up on the XY problem and post what you are really trying to do and we can post the answer.

Comment: my table contains 5 columns... i need count of data with distinct description (column in table) in a particular date

public Array[] GetItemsGraph<T>(DateTime d) where T : BL.Contracts.IBusinessEntity, new()
{
     var date = d.ToString ("dd/MM/yyyy");
 Array[] arr = {};

 lock (locker) {

 arr = Table<T>().Where(g => g.EventDateTimeUTC.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == date)
     .GroupBy(l => l.Description, 
              (Description,items) => new{ key= Description, count = items.Count()}).ToArray();

 return arr;
   }
}

Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1[]' to 'System.Array[]'

Comment: Code is unreadable in comments. Post your code as a new question, but be sure to explain what you are trying to do too in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly do not want `Array[]`, which is an array of arrays.  (With type erasure added to cause extra problems)